# No Notification Event for new ListItem in Google Sites List Page Template

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I need a notification event when a new item is added to the list in the Google Sites List Page Template. Something like Page.listUpdated(e) would be great, where e.Item could be the new ListItem.

Initially it would be to enable conditional formatting on new item, but I can think of alot more uses.

Can anyone suggest a workaround for this possibly?

Comment: Can you give some more information about your script and what you'r trying to do? Give the code for example.

Answer (score 0):

I have a script that runs in a spreadsheet that I use to keep track of changes in Calendars and that I slightly modified to check SitePage lists... It needs some 'cosmetic enhancements' but it works. You can set a time trigger to let it run every 30' for example and it will send you a mail if any change is made in any of your selected pages.

The only thing you have to do is to add the url of the pages you want to check on the 'master sheet' and run the 'init' function once before you try it.
The logger Sheet will keep track of the changes as well.

The test sheet is [available here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dF9vazZuOHQzMHFHWlJ2QXpiWnlSaGc) (please make a copy to run it) and the script goes like this  (consider this as a 'work in progress'):

```
  var email = 'test@gmail.com';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();// this spreadsheet
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('master');
  var pageList = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var logsheet = ss.getSheetByName('logger');
  var last = logsheet.getLastRow();
  var FUS1=new Date().toString().substr(25,6)+":00";

function onOpen() {
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "initialize", functionName: "init"},
                      {name: "Lauch autoTest", functionName: "autoCheckAllPages"},
                     ];
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    sheet.addMenu("Tracking utilities",menuEntries);//
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('logger'));// start on logger page  
}

function init(){
   ScriptProperties.setProperties({'lastTest': 'empty'}, true); 
}


function autoCheckAllPages(){
    var message = ScriptProperties.getProperty('lastTest')
    var newVal = ''
    ss.setActiveSheet(logsheet)
  for(nn=0;nn<pageList.length;++nn){
    var pageName = pageList[nn][0];
    var pageUrl = pageList[nn][1];   
    var items = SitesApp.getPageByUrl(pageUrl).getListItems()
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        Logger.log(items[i].getDatePublished()+'    '+items[i].getValueByIndex(1))
        newVal+= pageName+','+items[i].getDatePublished()+','+items[i].getValueByIndex(1)+'|'
        }
      }
    ScriptProperties.setProperties({'lastTest': newVal}, true);    // write to script properties       
    logsheet.insertRowAfter(last)
    logsheet.getRange(last+1,1).setValue('Autotest on '+ Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),FUS1,"MMM-dd-yy @ hh:mm"))
      if(message != newVal){
        var addedItem = sendMail_(message,newVal)
        logsheet.getRange(last+1,2).setValue('new list Item : '+addedItem)
        }
}


function sendMail_(message,newVal){
  Logger.log('send mail')
  var newItem=''
  var old=message
  var newI = newVal.split('|');
  for(n=0;n<newI.length;++n){
    if(message.match(newI[n])!=newI[n]){ newItem += newI[n] + '|'
    }
}
//MailApp.sendEmail(email,'new listItem Added',newItem);// this should be developped with HTML body to show date in a table for example...
return newItem
}
```